# Typescript variadic generic equivalent for return value

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have a function that accepts a generic type arguments, and returns a tuple of arrays of the same types, however this function can accept dynamic amount of those generics. Something like:

```
function myFunction<T1>(): [Array<T1>] {...}
function myFunction<T1, T2>(): [Array<T1>, Array<T2>] {...}
function myFunction<T1, T2, T3>(): [Array<T1>, Array<T2>, Array<T3>] {...}
```

and so on.

How do I define a single generic type T and equivalent return value so that I can pass as many different generic as I want?

I have tried doing it in a simple way like:

```
function myFunction<T extends any[]>(): Array<Array<T[number]>> {...}
```

However that loses information on what type is stored at which index.

I also tried something similar to this:

```
function myFunction<T extends any[]>(): {[key in keyof T]: Array<T[key]>} {...}
```

However calling keyof T on an Array returns other properties besides indexes like "length" etc. which also makes it a little problematic during assignment. Resulting in errors similar to this:

```
TS2322: Type 'string[][]' is not assignable to type '{ [x: number]: string[]; length: string[]; toString: string[]; toLocaleString: string[]; pop: string[]; push: string[]; concat: string[]; join: string[]; reverse: string[]; shift: string[]; slice: string[]; sort: string[]; splice: string[]; ... 25 more ...; at: string[]; }'.
```

Comment: Just to be sure, this function doesn't require any params?

Comment: [I don't see the problem](https://tsplay.dev/m35p3w).  Could you provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE that actually shows what the issue is?